# Displaying image in full width of web page

Tags: html, css

I have a Slider which contains images.Images Automatically slides as per the settings.My image size is `2000*400` .Now i want my images to show in full width of the webpage but it is showing in the middle of the webpage.
Here is the HTML..

```
   <div id="sliderFrame">
    <div id="slider">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" />

    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the Css..

```
 #sliderFrame 
  {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;

  }

 #slider, #slider div.sliderInner {
 width:100%;height:400px;/* Must be the same size as the slider images */
 }

#slider {
background:#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;
}

/* image wrapper */
#slider a.imgLink, #slider div.video {
z-index:2;
position:absolute;
top:0px;left:0px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;
width:100%;height:100%;
}
#slider .video {
background:transparent url(video.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

/* Caption styles */
#slider div.mc-caption-bg, #slider div.mc-caption-bg2 {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:auto;
padding:10px 0;/* 10px will increase the height.*/
left:0px; /*if the caption needs to be aligned from right, specify by right instead of left. i.e. right:20px;*/
bottom:0px;/*if the caption needs to be aligned from top, specify by top instead of bottom. i.e. top:150px;*/
z-index:3;
overflow:hidden;
font-size: 0;
}
#slider div.mc-caption-bg 
 {
/* NOTE: Its opacity is to be set through the sliderOptions.captionOpacity setting in the js-image-slider.js file.*/
background:Black;/* or any other colors such as White, or: background:none; */
}
#slider div.mc-caption-bg2 {
background:none;
}
#slider div.mc-caption {
font: bold 14px/20px Arial;
color:#EEE;
z-index:4;
text-align:center;
background:none;
}
#slider div.mc-caption a {
color:#FB0;
}
#slider div.mc-caption a:hover {
color:#DA0;
}


/* ------ built-in navigation bullets wrapper ------*/
/* Note: check themes\2\js-image-slider.css to see how to hide nav bullets */
#slider div.navBulletsWrapper  {
top:320px;/* Its position is relative to the #slider */
text-align:center;
background:none;
position:relative;
z-index:5;
}

/* each bullet */
#slider div.navBulletsWrapper div 
{
width:11px; height:11px;
font-size:0;color:White;/*hide the index number in the bullet element*/
background:transparent url(bullet.png) no-repeat 0 0;
display:inline-block; display:inline; zoom:1;
overflow:hidden;cursor:pointer;
margin:0 6px;/* set distance between each bullet*/
}

#slider div.navBulletsWrapper div.active {background-position:0 -11px;}


/* --------- Others ------- */

#slider div.loading 
{
width:100%; height:100%;
background:transparent url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
opacity:0.6;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0; 
z-index:9;
}

#slider img, #slider>b, #slider a>b {
position:absolute; border:none; display:none;
}

#slider div.sliderInner {
overflow:hidden; 
-webkit-transform: rotate(0.000001deg);/* fixed the Chrome not crop border-radius bug*/
position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
}

#slider>a, #slider video, #slider audio {display:none;}
```

Please help me .

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please create a fiddle.

Comment: where is div.sliderInner in the markup, and why no width specified for images in css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
#slider img
{
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Sir i have updated my post with all the css for this div.Please hava look.Thanks

Comment: #slider img, #slider>b, #slider a>b {
position:absolute; border:none; display:none;width:100%;
} should work, If the dimensions are not dynamically changed by plug-in.

Comment: Now its coming sir ,But one thing that i have seen here is that image is not coming fully .It is getting cut at right side of the webpage.So what to do to show full image.Also if any standard size so that all browsers can support

Comment: Check if parent divs of <div id="sliderFrame"> may have some CSS class/style which may cause this. You can check that in Element Inspector(right click on the page or by pressing F12 key)

Comment: Whatever css is being used by slider i have updated in my post Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width on slider so that it occupies the entire width. And set the width of the image to 100% with auto height. This will scale the images to fill the width.

```
#sliderFrame {
    position: relative;
    /* width: 2000px; */
}
#sliderFrame img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Sir i tried to implement your solution but it is not working in my case so i have updated my post with All the css .Please have a look.Thanks

Comment: R u looking into sir?